# Probability Bertrand paradox

Tags: probability

I wanted to ask about Bertrand paradox.

aka:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_(probability)

There are 3 different solutions that suggested in the line, and each one of them leads to a different answer ($ 1/3, 1/4, 1/2 $ )

Now, my friend wrote a Python code that checks for given variable of trials:

(its a bit different but actually the same expirement, we chose randomly a chord and ask if its length is more then $ \sqrt(3)*radius $:

```
import random
import math

r = 1     ##insert radius here
k = 10000000 ###insert number of checks here
target_check = r*math.sqrt(3)
counter = 0
for i in range(k):
    x1 = random.uniform(-r, r)
    x2 = random.uniform(-r, r)
    if math.sqrt((x1-x2)**2 + (math.sqrt(r**2-x1**2)-math.sqrt(r**2-x2**2))**2) >= target_check:
        counter += 1

print("Total Percentage of Strings larger than r*sqrt(3) is: ", 100*counter/k, "%")
```

I've run this code a few times and noticed that the result actually is getting closer to $ 3% $. I wonder how come this program output tend to such difference from all the theoretic answers.
Can anyone provide an explanation for that?

Explanation of the code:

It grabs 2 $ x $ corrdinates $ x_1 $ and $ x_2 $ from points on the circle, in order to find the $ y $ corrdinate of each selected $ x $ we use the circle equation:

$ x^2+y^2=r^2 $

thus $ \sqrt{r^2-x_1^2}=y_1 $ and $ \sqrt{r^2-x_2^2}=y_2 $

and then we ask if the the chord length is bigger than $ \sqrt{3} * radius $ which would be the triangle length, using the distance equation

edit:
I have read the comments and changed the code:

```
import math
import random


##Consider an equiliteral triangle inscribed  in a circle.
##Suppose a chord of the circle is chosen at random.
##What is the probability that the chord is longer than a side of the triangle?



number_of_trials=100000    #enter number of trials here.

radius=1 #enter the radius of the circle here,default would be 1.

successful_trials=0

for n in range(number_of_trials):
    rand_angle1=random.uniform(0,2*math.pi)
    rand_angle2=random.uniform(0,2*math.pi)
    
    x1=radius*math.cos(rand_angle1)
    y1=radius*math.sin(rand_angle1)
    
    x2=radius*math.cos(rand_angle2)
    y2=radius*math.sin(rand_angle2)
    
    if math.sqrt((x1-x2)**2+(y1-y2)**2)>radius*math.sqrt(3):
        successful_trials+=1
        
print('Total precentege of chords larger than the side of the triangle is {}%'.format(100*successful_trials/number_of_trials))
```

Now it seems that the probability tends to be $1/3$. Do you think its reliable or do you recognise some more problems?

Comment: I don't understand.  Are you saying that only $3\%$ of the chords are longer than the equilateral triangle length?  More to the point, I can't understand the function you compute.

Comment: Can you explain the geometric meaning of $\sqrt{(X_1-X_2)^2 + \left ( \sqrt{r^2-X_1^2}-\sqrt{r^2-X_2^2} \right )^2} \geq \sqrt{3}r$? Which selection method is this supposed to encode?

Comment: @Ian Thats the length of the chord. $ X_1 $ and $ X_2 $ are the random $ x $ values of two points in the circle. $ \sqrt{r^2-X_1^2} $ is the $ y_1 $ coordinate that correspond to $ x_1 $ coordinate (the point is $ (x_1,y_1 ) $ )

Comment: @lulu yes, only 3% of the chords are longer

Comment: This is very hard to follow.  It appears that all your $y-$coordinates lie on or above the $x-$axis, yes?  Why would you want that?

Comment: But your chords computed by that method always go from one point on the *upper* half of the circle to another point on the upper half.

Comment: Alright, I see two problems now. The first one is that your $y$ coordinates are never negative, so actually all your points are drawn from the top half of the circle. You might try to patch that by just "flipping a coin" to set the sign, but that wouldn't fix the second problem, which is that you're not drawing points uniformly along the length of the semicircle. There is a bias in this construction. To get points uniformly along the length of the circle, use $(\cos(U),\sin(U))$ where $U$ is uniformly distributed on $(0,2\pi)$ (or whatever other interval of length $2\pi$ you prefer).

Comment: @Ian I see. thanks!

Comment: @Ian I took your advise and changed the code. Can you tell what you think now?

Comment: Looks like you've got the "random endpoints" version of Bertrand's paradox running correctly now.